# Uncompressed panoramas on iPhone as of iOS 7.1.x

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use the trick with HiddenSettings7 to have a panorama for my lock screen, which scrolls as I move the phone (something similar to the feature included in the iOS 7 beta). However, as of iOS 7.1.x, as the Internet tells me, file browsers (more specifically afc2add) do not work, meaning I can't get uncompressed panoramas by inserting them onto the file system's wallpapers folder by using a PC file browser. Saving to the camera roll creates lots of compression, and it's a route I'd rather not take. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

afc2add's successor, Apple File Conduit, provides the same (and more) functionality as it's predecessor, and supports iOS 7.1.x.